# Alert between 2 functions

Tags: javascript

i am stuck with something between 2 functions here is my link to codepen to see what i am trying to do [Demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLLrBX?editors=1010)

```
function displayImage(elem) {
var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
image.src = elem.value;        
 }
  function displayImages(elem) {
 var image = document.getElementById("canvass");
 image.src = elem.value;        
 }
  function same() {
   if(displayImages(elem) === displayImage(elem)){
   alert("same");
   }
  }
```

So basically if select 1 have the same link with selected2 to alert same.

Comment: What is `elem` in the `same` function? You're not calling your `same` function anywhere. You're not returning anything from `displayImage` or `displayImages`, hence `undefined` will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're comparing the wrong values. In this case you need to compare the sources of the images.

```
function same() {
  if (document.getElementById("canvas").src == document.getElementById("canvass").src) {
    alert("same")
  }
}
```

Comment: hi,i test this and still not working i am doing something wrong?thanks!

Comment: Thank you! is working very well. Sorry guys i am at beginning with javascript.Have a nice day!

Comment: If this answer worked, please mark it as 'accepted' by pressing the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I can`t i tried i need to wait 4 mins. i will do it!